# Getting Error while creating table in Kustodb from azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-explorer, kql

When I'm trying to create table in Azure Data explorer database from Azure Pipeline I'm getting below error.

**Error**

##[error]Service returned an error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND testdbprod.kusto.windows.net testdbprod.kusto.windows.net:443 server: testdbprod.kusto.windows.net database: testprod-prod command: .create-merge table Notifications (Timestamp: datetime, NoteType: string, homename: string, Value: string)

Pipeline.yaml

```
- task: ADXQuery@1
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: '.create-merge table Notifications (Timestamp: datetime, NoteType: string, homename: string, Value: string)'
    kustoUrls: 'https://testdbprod.kusto.windows.net:443?DatabaseName=testprod-prod'
    customAuth: false
    ResourceURI: 'https://testdbprod.kusto.windows.net'
    aadClientId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx'
    aadClientSecret: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    tenantId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    minThreshold: '0'
    maxThreshold: '0'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the cluster URL you provided is invalid.